# Conditional render classes based on url in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to show different navigations based on if it is the "Homepage" or if it is a page that contains "docs" (e.g. docs/1, docs/2, docs/3) in its URL.
I'm just getting blanks on the "docs"-case - it feels like I am missing something here?

Here's my code so far:

```
const router = useRouter()
const path = router?.asPath

if (path === '/docs/') {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{pageTitle}</title>
        {description && <meta name="description" content={description} />}
      </Head>
      <Layout
        navigation={navigation1}
        title={title}
        tableOfContents={tableOfContents}
      >
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}
if (path === '/') {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{pageTitle}</title>
        {description && <meta name="description" content={description} />}
      </Head>
      <Layout
        navigation={navigation}
        title={title}
        tableOfContents={tableOfContents}
      >
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: That's most likely because the path is not `/docs/` for those routes. Have you tried something like: `if (path.includes('/docs') { ... }`?

Comment: Thanks, the "includes" did the trick!

Comment: Following up on this one to see if anyone have any guidance.

This below worked very well:
 let isDocs = router.pathname.includes('/docs')

But then I decided to add a language folder so the new url became en/docs and:
let isDocs = router.pathname.includes('/en/docs')

But that seemed to break the whole thing. Any suggestion or guidance what might have caused it to stop working?

Comment: `router.pathname.includes('/docs')` would still work even with the locale in the path.

Answer (score 2):

NextJS has a built-in route system. You can just create a docs.js file in the pages folder. You can either create different navigations directly in /pages/docs.js or a dynamic component for it.

Here is more about routing https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction

Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I might have been a little bit unclear in my post, when I refer to "navigation" I refer to different headers. So, I'd like to display different classes depending on the URL, if that makes sense :)

Comment: No problem! Have you checked what path actually returns? The path may just be "/docs" instead of "/docs/".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have fixed this but I have completed the same method with the following code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const ComponentName = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { pathname } = router;
    if (pathname.includes('/')) {
       // Add home component
    } else {
       // Add another component instead
    }
}
export default ComponentName
```

You can then use conditional statements to check what the path is just like you were doing.

**- Tested with Next JS V13**

Answer (score 0):

In NextJS v14+, I'm seeing (similar to [Julian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75476019/3780197), but with "usePathname" instead of "useRouter"). I'm familiar with the dynamic routes, but in my case, the condition needed to happen on the home page, which is handled by the top-level `layout.tsx` file, so I was unable to use the dynamic routes to capture the condition. Here's my solution:

```
"use client";

import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function ComponentName {
  const path = usePathname();
  
  return (
    { // Only render this on home page
      path === "/" && <ConditionalComponent />
    }
    {/* Default components */}
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
    ...
  );
};
```